# Error when using yup with formik about '.matches': yup__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.number().matches is not a function

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

Here is part of my code that I get error:

```
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            code: '', name: '', tankVolume: '', mobile: '', city: '', province: '', driverType: '', numberPlate: '', description: ''
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
            code: Yup.number().matches(/[0-9]{10}/, 'not valid').required('some error').typeError('some error'),
           .
           .
           ..other validations
        }),
        onSubmit: values => {
            console.log('submitted')
            formik.resetForm()
        }
    })
```

> Error: yup__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.number().matches is not a
> function

Other validations work fine, it just throws an error when I want to use `.matches`